# Read-only controls in XsltForms

Tags: xsltforms

I was trying to set an input control as "read-only", but it doesn't work as explained in [Equivalent XSLTForms class values](http://en.wikibooks.org/wiki/XSLTForms/CSS).

```
<xf:input ref="instance('person')/@name" class="xforms-readonly">
    <xf:label>Name:</xf:label>
</xf:input>
```

Any idea why? I'm trying to avoid using CSS and use 100% xforms capabilities.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is a major feature of XForms to consider properties, such as `readonly`, at data level not at control level.

So, this has to be decided with a binding within the model.

The CSS class `xforms-readonly` is automatically associated/removed by XSLTForms according to the effective status of the corresponding node.